# Bulk remove a special letter in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Edited:

Lets say I have a Mongo Database with a collection, lets call it products. In this collection I want to remove all special characters, lets say all dots, from all entries in a certain field, lets say price. 
Also, how would i replace for example the info entries of all of my objects?

How would I do this through the mongo shell?

```
Example:

_id: 123324erwerew
name: 'moisture cream'
price: 30.00
info: 'Good Cream'

_id: 343324erwerew
name: 'moisture cream two'
price: 40.00
info: 'Good Cream also'
```

Lets say info in both of them should be : "best cream ever" and the dots should be gone for both prices

Comment: Please provide a sample document.

Comment: updated with examples and slightly different question

Comment: What is the data type of the price field? Is it NumberDecimal and you are trying to remove the decimal point?

Comment: Is the field `price` a _string_ or a number. If its a number what is the number type (double. float. NumberDecimal)? If the `price` values are to be like `price: 30.00` the type must one of string or [NumberDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#numberdecimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your prices were like `30.11` and `40.11` the following pipeline update command would make the prices `"3011"` and `"4011"` as well as set info to `best cream ever`

```
db.products.updateMany({}, [
    {
        $set: {
            price: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $split: [{ $toString: "$price" }, "."] },
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: { $concat: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            info: "best cream ever"
        }
    }
])
```

explanation about price update:

1. value of price is converted to a string
2. the resulting string is split by delimiter `.`
3. resulting parts are then concatenated back to a string with the use of $reduce

in mongodb v4.4 this is much simplified with the [$replaceOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/#exp._S_replaceOne) operator